Map and marker do not show after getting data from OpenStreet Nominatim in OpenLayers
I have made this code and it works in my test file, only it dows NOT execute the COMPLETED line. However if the complete code is moved to my target file it does NOT show map and marker. All StatusInfo are released, but again NOT the COMPLETED.
Both have exactly the same code only difference is from production file the script is triggered from an AJAX collected file.
OpenLayers is version 6.1.1
HTML:
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v6.1.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v6.1.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        #popup {
                    border: solid 2px black;
                    background-color: #fff;
        }
                    
    </style>

    <div id="map" style="height: 400px; width: 100%;"></div>
    <div id="popup"><div id="popup-content"></div></div>
    <div id="datainfo" style="position: absolute; top: 75%; width: 99%; height: 20%; border: solid 1px black"></div>

...........


JS/JQuery script
var mapLng = 0.0;
var mapLat = 0.0;

const sted = 'Radisson Hotel';

const byen = 'München';

const land = 'DE';
    
const landet = 'Germany';

   if (byen.indexOf(',') > 0)
   {
         byenogstate = byen.replace(', ','&state=');
         byenogstate = byenogstate+'&country='+land;
   }
   else
   {
      byenogstate = byen+'&state=&country='+land;
   }
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?city="+byenogstate+"&format=json", // Obtaining JSON data from OpenStreet
        success: function(result) {
                                    mapLat = result[0].lat;
                                    mapLng = result[0].lon;
                                    
///SHOW MAP
 StatusInfo = 'OpenStreet WORKS - Long: '+mapLng+', Lati: '+ mapLat+', Place: '+sted+', TownAndState: '+byenogstate;
 $('#datainfo').html(StatusInfo);
                                    const map = new ol.Map({
                                                            target: 'map',
                                                            layers: [ new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM() })],
                                                            view: new ol.View({
                                                                                center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([mapLng,mapLat]),
                                                                                zoom: 10
                                                                            })
                                                        });  // Seems to work however no MAP is shown
 StatusInfo +='<br />Map WORKS - Long: '+mapLng+', Lati: '+ mapLat+', Place: '+sted+', TownAndState: '+byenogstate;
 $('#datainfo').html(StatusInfo);
///ADD MARKER

                                    var markers = new ol.layer.Vector({
                                                                        source: new ol.source.Vector(),
                                                                        style: new ol.style.Style({
                                                                                                    image: new ol.style.Icon({
                                                                                                                                anchor: [0.5, 1],
                                                                                                                                src: 'marker.png'
                                                                                                    })
                                                                        })
                                    });
                                    map.addLayer(markers);
    
                                    var marker = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([mapLng,mapLat])));
                                    markers.getSource().addFeature(marker); // Seems to work however no MARKER is shown

 StatusInfo +='<br />Marker WORKS - Long: '+mapLng+', Lati: '+ mapLat+', Place: '+sted+', TownAndState: '+byenogstate;
 $('#datainfo').html(StatusInfo);
// ADD POPUP
                                    var container = document.getElementById('popup');
                                    var content = document.getElementById('popup-content');

                                    var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
                                                                    element: container,
                                                                    autoPan: true,
                                                                    autoPanAnimation: {
                                                                                        duration: 250
                                                                    }
                                    });
                                    map.addOverlay(overlay);  
                                    
 StatusInfo +='<br />Popup WORKS - Long: '+mapLng+', Lati: '+ mapLat+', Place: '+sted+', TownAndState: '+byenogstate;
 $('#datainfo').html(StatusInfo);

                                    StedInfo = '&nbsp;'+sted.replace("'","\\'")+'&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;'+byen.replace("'","\\'");
                                    
                                    StedInfo += '&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;<img src="./getflag.php?p='+land+'" /> '+landet+'&nbsp;';
  
                                    content.innerHTML = StedInfo;  // Last line working
                                    
                                    overlay.setPosition(ol.proj.fromLonLat([mapLng,mapLat]));

 // This line fails
 StatusInfo +='<br />COMPLETED - Long: '+mapLng+', Lati: '+ mapLat+', Place: '+sted+', TownAndState: '+byenogstate;
 $('#datainfo').html(StatusInfo);
                                    
                 }   
    });



Original files can be found here
